React: How to run one app inside shadow dom of main app?
For context, I am using vite, but I believe the issue would be the same with next.js.
With React, I have my "main app" and "module app" for example chat client. I don’t want to use iframe of "module app" inside "main app" or make static build of "modeule app" and insert it as /public static lib and also I don't want to merge their components, libs, public files to single app.
Is there solution to use second app as a component with own dependencies, public, src, tsconfig and so on?
May be like using
    <div id="app"></div>
    <div id="module_app"></div>

inside index.html or
    <div id=“module_app”></div>

somewhere deeper in react app?
And of course shadow root is needed here to escape apps global styles.
The scenario of a question is I have many standalone apps as a web chat, picture editor, accounting documents creator, server monitoring and more, each of them has own git repo. Each of them perfecly works as standalone app and now I need to use some of them as part of main app.

Node.JS doesn't support HTML. Maybe you've got your title and tags wrong? Or perhaps some clarification is appropriate. Are you just asking how to make separate javascript modules?

Yes, based on multiple stanalone apps.

I asked multiple questions there. Does your question have anything to do with node.js, or is this an HTML / browser JavaScript question?

Yes, By this HTML I mean create two roots and render two separate apps to it.

I did it again. Does your question have anything to do with node.js?

that is what I trying I failed:
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
const domNode1 = document.getElementById('app1');
const domNode2 = document.getElementById('app2');
const root1 = createRoot(domNode1);
const root2 = createRoot(domNode1);
root1.render();
root2.render();
so is Node.JS wrong tag?

This question is similar to: How to render a React app in a React app (nested React apps). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

oh okay, ModuleFederationPlugin make sense thank you. Didn't search "React to React" because in my case it Svelte to React and Vue to React. Will try this.
